# How to show terms with a specific depth as exposed filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

I would like, on Drupal 9, to show in a view as exposed filter a taxonomy term with depth 0, one with level one (the children) and one with level 2 (level one's children).

Basically I have a content type that has a taxonomy term reference field to a vocabulary that has up to three levels of depth.
I'd like to make 3 exposed select, as in the screen [image]
So, showing the first level as one select, then enable the second select if the term selected first has children and again enable the third select if the second term has children too.

I'm trying to do it with standard view, but I cannot figure how.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Drupal core, you'll need to install the [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) contrib module.